# Reference to Arrays and Order

Tags: perl, hash

Suppose that I have a hash in which the key/value pair is as follows:

```
Name  Scores
Bob 67 89 77 89
Kim 99 98 95 90
Dan 67 90 73 88
   . . .goes on
```

The keys are names and the values are test scores. Now the values refer to arrays.

I understand that there is a sort function for a hash, but suppose that I want to find the median score for each student.

Final output:

```
Name Median 
Bob 83
( . . .and so on)
```

To find the median, I need to first place the scores in order of lowest to highest magnitude.
Is there a sort function for hashes in which I can order the test scores for each student?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: +1 for well formatted 1st question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing the builtin `sort` can sort is a list of scalars; it can't sort hashes. In fact, it's impossible to sort a hash. Instead, one sorts the keys of the hash. One could just as easily sort the indexes of an array, but such an indirection is completely unnecessary here.

You have a list of numbers, and you want to sort that list of numbers without need of any outside information.

```
my @sorted_scores = sort { $a <=> $b } @scores;
```

which is to say

```
my @sorted_scores = sort { $a <=> $b } @{ $scores{'Bob'} };
```

The median would be

```
my $mid_idx = int(@sorted_scores / 2);
my $median = @sorted_scores % 2
   ? $sorted_scores[$mid_idx]
   : ( $sorted_scores[$mid_idx-1] + $sorted_scores[$mid_idx-0] ) / 2;
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thank you for your help. I know that I can identify each score as $hash{$student}[index number], right? But how would I use this if I wanted the output to give me name and one specific score after ordering?

Comment: The best score out of the four in the hash. Would I have to define the index? (Or could I just use 0 in place of index number as I have above?)

Comment: Normally, I'd say `max @{ $scores{'Bob'} }`. But since you're already sorting the scores, `$sorted_scores[-1]`. (List::Util provides `max`.)

Comment: Also, sorry, I thought of another question. In @scores, what is the order of the score sets? How does the order of the score sets correspond to the names? (If scores array is a list of each student's score set, then  how do I know which score set belongs to which student?)

Comment: Could you please explain the syntax `$sorted_scores[-1]`? What does [-1] mean?

Comment: [Subscripts in perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Subscripts). -1 indicates the last element.

Comment: `my @sorted_scores = sort { $a <=> $b } @{ $scores{'Bob'} };` I get an error message for an undefined value. But I have typed my line `@sorted_scores = sort { $a <=> $b } @{ $hash{'$name'} };` instead. Any ideas what I did wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You assumed I could read your mind. You didn't post your data structure, much less the name of the variables you used.

Comment: And always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: Which variables do you mean?

Comment: I have the names (keys) and scores (values) in a hash. I have $scores = testscores ('100'), $names = student names ('Bob'), and hash name is class (%class). Since I won't be dealing with multi-D arrays, I didn't include any variables for indexes in multi-D arrays. So from your example: `my @sorted_scores = sort { $a <=> $b } @{ $scores{$name} };` and not `my @sorted_scores = sort { $a <=> $b } @{ $class{$name} };`? Best score would be `$best = $sorted_scores[-1];`?

Comment: @Hipale, You need a hash of array of scores indexed by name (`$scores{$name}`). `$scores` can't possibly be that, but if that's a ref to HoA of scored indexed by name, you can use `@{ $scores->{$name} }`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this module :

[Statistics::Basic::Median](https://metacpan.org/module/Statistics%3a%3aBasic%3a%3aMedian)